# Two plus divs, a, h2, css hover

Tags: html, css

I have:

```
<div class="item">
    <div class="thumb">
        <a class="clip-link" data-id="17228" href="http://t3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTR6pGMoMUINSzoWyR0J_a1fAR9W0DsMjlOGQ-12W8jFiQmPW6B">
            <span class="clip">
                <img src="http://t3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTR6pGMoMUINSzoWyR0J_a1fAR9W0DsMjlOGQ-12W8jFiQmPW6B">
            </span>                         
            <span class="overlay"></span>
        </a>
    </div>          
        <div class="data">
            <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="http://t3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTR6pGMoMUINSzoWyR0J_a1fAR9W0DsMjlOGQ-12W8jFiQmPW6B" rel="bookmark">my title</a></h2>

            <p class="entry-meta">
                <span class="author vcard">
                <a class="author" href="http://t3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTR6pGMoMUINSzoWyR0J_a1fAR9W0DsMjlOGQ-12W8jFiQmPW6B" rel="author">Author</a></span>
            </p>
        </div>
```

With css:

```
.item:hover h2 a {
color: #B70000;
}

a:hover {
color: #B70000;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ebB4p/7/

I want to back "my title" to blue while hovering over author.

Comment: What's the restrictions here, can't you just change the html?

Comment: I could change the html code if there is no css could sort this out.

Comment: It's unclear what you want

Comment: You're making it appear from a UX standpoint that clicking on the image points to the same URL as clicking on the title, when it doesn't, which is bad practice, hence the -1

Comment: @Mr. Alien, when you see example and hover over thumbnail, than "my title", than "author", you will realize what I want. Hover over author shows "my title" red colored, and I don't want it to be red. Many times I stuck on this and had to change html, no other way I can explain, just see exampe, it shows the question.

Comment: @user3114390 Got it now, you should ask, color the title when hovered on image.. and anyways upvoted because you have tried it yourself so no reason why other user downvoted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just target the `a:hover` and not the  `a` inside `item`

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ebB4p/1/)

**EDIT**

New [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ebB4p/2/)

this targets the hover on `.thumb` and it's sibling `.data` and moves down the list to get to the `a` tag which is your title

```
.thumb:hover + .data .entry-title a{
    color: #B70000;
}
```

Comment: Hover doesn't work on thumbnail if I do so. Hover over thumbnail needs to show "my title" red colored.

Comment: @user3114390 Sorry i didnt realize that's what you were trying to do, updating my answer

Comment: @xec will do, updating now

Comment: @jmore009 your both the fiddles do the same thing, Edit: oh now I see the change.. +1